# How to split string into parts with N letters in each using Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, split

I need to split a string into a few parts that contain N letters each.
For example

```
str = "Hello World! Kotlin is amazing!"
split_into_n(str, 3) = ["Hel", "lo ", "Wor", "ld!", " Ko", "tli", "n i", "s a", "maz", "ing", "!"]
```

I have tried [regex](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/), but it does not seem to work.
I have tried using split methods but it doesn't work either.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you show your attempt with regexes?

Comment: Yes, sure.
`fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  
    val my_string = "Hello World! Kotlin is amazing!"
  
    print("/.{1,3}/g".toRegex().matchEntire(names)?.groups?.get(1)?.value)
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`chunked()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/chunked.html) extension function does exactly this:

```
val str = "Hello World! Kotlin is amazing!"
println(str.chunked(3))
// [Hel, lo , Wor, ld!,  Ko, tli, n i, s a, maz, ing, !]
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of the resulting array will be the length of the original array divided by N but if there is a remainder, you need an additional element.

```kotlin
val result=Array<String>(str.length/n+(str.length%n).sign())
```

`str.length/n` is the resulting length without the last element if the original lebgth is not dividable by `n`.

`str.length%n` results in `0` if the length is dividable by `n` and a positive number (remainder) if it is not.

[`sign`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/sign.html) returns `1` if the value is positive and `0` if the value is `0`.

After that, you can just fill the array with substrings:

```kotlin
for(i in 0..result.length){
    result[i]=str.substring(i*n,min((i+1)*n,str.length))
}
```

This loops over all indexes of the resulting array and sets the corresponding elements to substrings of `str`.

The start index is the index of the resulting array multiplied by 3 and the end index is the index before the next element (or the last total length).

Combined, it would look like this:

```kotlin
import kotlin.math
fun splitIntoN(str,n){
    val result=Array<String>(str.length/n+(str.length%n).sign())
    for(i in 0..result.length){
        result[i]=str.substring(i*n,min((i+1)*n,str.length))
    }
}
```